# laravel date default error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I always install laravel v5 and after completing it's install when i view to the new installation the errors come out

> Warning: date_default_timezone_set(): It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone. in D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1808
>
> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in
>   D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1808
>
> Warning:
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandlers():
>   It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are
>   *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1673
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler()
>   in D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1673

But everything fine for v4.2.0 and it working i want to use v5 so please tell me. 

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can set timezone in **config** file `app/config/app.php` or any `app/config/environment/app.php` at below section.

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
| 
*/

// Default value of timezone is 'UTC', I have changed it to 'Asia/Kolkata'

'timezone'  => 'Asia/Kolkata',
```

Comment: I did what you told and even add the same timezone in php.ini and restarted I am getting this error

Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1808

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler() in D:\vendor\compiled.php on line 1673

Comment: 'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Kolkata'),